# Test value of a HashSet in a FitNesse table cell?

Tags: hashset, fitnesse, fitsharp

Using FitNesse with FitSharp (.Net), I've got a property of an object that is a HashSet of an enum, e.g.

```
public enum Fubar { Foo, Bar }

public class Test
{
   public HashSet<Fubar> SetOfFubar { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to test it simply, for example in an array fixture like so:

```
|MyArrayFixture|
|SetOfFubar|
|Foo|
|Foo,Bar|
|Bar|
||
```

This simply results in all rows marked missing & red and a set of surplus rows showing something like:

```
System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[MyNamespace.Fubar] surplus
```

What's the easiest way to get FitNesse with FitSharp (.Net) to understand HashSets?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a parse operator.  Here's a little example from http://fitsharp.github.io/Fit/WriteOurOwnCellOperator.html that parses the string"pi" into a numeric value.

> ```
> using fitSharp.Fit.Operators;
> using fitSharp.Machine.Engine;
> public class ParsePi: CellOperator, ParseOperator<Cell> {
> ```
>
> The CanParse method override determines which cells are processed by
>   our operator. We check for "pi" in the cell and also that we are
>   working with a numeric type. This preserves normal behavior if we're
>   using "pi" as a string input or expected value.
>
> ```
>   public bool CanParse(Type type, TypedValue instance, Tree<Cell> parameters) {
>     return type == typeof(double) && parameters.Value.Text == "pi";
>   }
> ```
>
> Overriding the Parse method changes the behavior when the cell is
>   parsed to create an input or an expected value.
>
> ```
>   public TypedValue Parse(Type type, TypedValue instance, TreeTree<Cell> parameters) {
>     return new TypedValue(System.Math.PI);
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: I already tried that at first. The code sample shows how to create a new parse operator but even though I registered it, I just couldn't get FitNesse to call the Parse method for the cell in question. In the end I gave up and went for a different solution.